# Dynamic Formula Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like below:

[image]

[image]

I need a function which takes value from the second table and as per formula it calculates and returns the calculation value.

Is it possible in one function??
Regards,

Comment: If you mean dynamically read a formula and apply it then it will be **very** hard on SQL. If your formulas are static you can mimic their calculus. We need sample data and expected outcome here.

Comment: I guess you can build a query using dynamic sql to query  the second table and use the returned values  in the formula and then execute it but it looks tricky.

Comment: Why does PAY2 reference itself?

Comment: Requirements like this are always a concern in my view. As the other's have said, the only way would be with Dynamic SQL, but they you're placing possibly "unsanitised" SQL in your table, which could just be run. Someone malicious could they take advantage of that to inject unless you take very careful steps to make the values safe, and limit who can put data into those tables (maybe with validation of somekind at `INSERT`/`UPDATE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write dynamic SQL, with cross applies for each calculation, but you have to be careful of the risks that @Larnu mentions in the comments:

> Requirements like this are always a concern in my view. As the other's
>   have said, the only way would be with Dynamic SQL, but they you're
>   placing possibly "unsanitised" SQL in your table, which could just be
>   run. Someone malicious could they take advantage of that to inject
>   unless you take very careful steps to make the values safe, and limit
>   who can put data into those tables (maybe with validation of somekind
>   at INSERT/UPDATE)

Also, it wont work if the formula references itself (PAY2) and they must be sequentially defined. Here is an approach

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1  (ID VARCHAR(5), formula VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #table2  (employeid VARCHAR(5), payhead VARCHAR(5), amount MONEY)
CREATE TABLE #table3  (employeid VARCHAR(5), payiD VARCHAR(5), amount MONEY)

INSERT #Table1 VALUES ('PAY1',NULL), ('PAY2', '(PAY1*12%)'), ('PAY3', 'PAY1 + PAY2')
INSERT #Table2 VALUES ('E001','PAY1', 2000),('E002','PAY1', 5000),('E003','PAY1', 3000)

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR (MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ' + ID + ' = ' + REPLACE(formula,'%','/100') + '
)
AS ' + ID + '
'
FROM #Table1
WHERE formula is not null


SET @SQL = '
;WITH cte AS( 
SELECT employeid, Amount as Pay1 
FROM #table2
)
SELECT * 
INTO #TMP -- insert the result into a new temp table
FROM
cte ' + @SQL + '

INSERT #Table3
SELECT EmployeID, PayID, Amount
FROM #TMP
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ' + STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + '(''' + ID + ''',' + ID + ')' FROM 
             #Table1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
           ) + '
) A(PayID, Amount)
SELECT * FROM #TMP
DROP TABLE #TMP'


PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM #table3

DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
DROP TABLE #table3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support,

Comment: is there any other way like pay1*12%

Comment: You can use REPLACE(formula,'%','/100') ??

Comment: how can insert @sQL value in another table ?my table column is Empid,payid,amount.i want to insert each employee data into this table like,  E1,PAY1,5000----E1,PAY2,600---E1,PAY3,100 Like this from this dynamic query.pls help

Comment: It may have syntax error, I'm not using my laptop and I don't have SQL here to validate, but if you understand the concept you can fix it..

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. but it does not throw any error also not inserted any data into the table. can you please help me out.

Comment: Done, as you could see in the messages window.. it is generating exactly the same code, but I had to run it in the same exec, do you have clear why??

Comment: Oops!forget to update you that i just apply in my original table as per your code.so it execute there but not insert into the table.but it is my mistake that i have to check in your code first.sorry for that.Thank you Daniel.. let me check with my table and let you update.

Answer (score 0):

Try a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.wage (@type varchar(10), @amount double)  
RETURNS double  
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
AS  
BEGIN 

if(@type='pay1') return(@amount)
if(@type='pay3') return(@amount*0.12)
if (@type='pay4') return((@amount+<pay2>)*(<pay2>-@amount*0.12)*0.01 ) 
if (@type='pay2') return(NULL)-- I think there's an error as it self-referenced   
END
```

just 'rewrite' the calculation in each return statement

Call like this:

```
select dbo.wage('pay3',3000.0)
```

Eventually you can add a 'help table' in wich you put the percentages if those vary with time and update the function to get also a date

Comment: How to do it dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean with 'dynamically'?

Comment: instead of if (@type='Pay2') i need dynamically from database bcoz Pay1,Pay2 are master table record and it may be 20 or 30 payhead.so it is not possible to do it static manner with if and else.so i need to pass payid and amount and it fetch formula from formula column and calculates the value.